# Loading two separate versions of moment.js using SystemJS and JSPM

Tags: ecmascript-6, systemjs, jspm, package.json, es6-modules

Disclaimer: this is a hypothetical scenario.

Suppose I have two ES6 modules, `module-a` which depends on `momentjs@1.x`  and `module-b` which depends on `momentjs@2.x`.

How do I structure the SystemJS / JSPM configuration and the module import statements such that `module-a` gets `momentjs@1.x` and `module-b` gets `momentjs@2.x`?